# Implementing a bubble sort to a class with multiple variable types in C#

Tags: c#, class, sorting, bubble-sort

I have a class that contains a few strings, as well as a few integer values. The program needs to use bubble sort to sort by a specific integer within called studentID.

The issue I'm coming across is accessing the variable properly. We are required to keep the variables within the class private, so the raw values aren't directly accessible from anywhere other than inside the actual class.

I've got something like this set up

```
public class Student {
    // PRIVATE strings and ints

    public Student() {
        // set variables to text fields
    }

    public void bubbleSort() {
        int i, j, temp;

        for (i = (x-1); i >= 0; i--) {    
            for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {    
                if(x[j - 1] > students[j]) {
                    temp = x[j - 1];
                    x[j - 1] = x[j];
                    x[j] = temp; 
                }
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

For every occurrence of X, I need to have the value of myStudent.studentID. The bubble sort is meant to be implemented within the class, but I can't figure out how to call it. With the needed fields set to private, I can find no way to pull the information to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) to expose private fields to the outside.

```
private string text = "";

public string Text
{
  get { return text; }
  set { text = value; }
}
```

If you aren't allowed to do that, you should talk with your teacher, as interacting with the class isn't possible then.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll proceed with that and if there is an issue come Tuesday I will have to talk with him.

Comment: I'm quite positive you should be allowed to use properties. Exposing fields is bad practise (as the class doesn't control the access and can't react to changes), but properties are there to mitigate that problem.

Comment: Needlessly exposing a writable property is nearly as bad. For most purposes this code is equivalent to a public field. (It has different reflection and *binary* versioning semantics)

Comment: This was as a general example a property, that's why I also linked the respective msdn article so he could read up on it.

Comment: To be honest, at this point I'm just looking for something that works, regardless of what the best option may be. Femaref, I've got it going okay. Turns out, however, that I need to be sorting by a string. Easiest way to compare two strings?

Comment: Exposing internals through a property for the sake of being able to sort is a bad idea. If the wish is for objects of a class to be comparable then implement IComparable<T> instead

Answer (score 3):

Implement [IComparable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727) interface in Student class, and then use CompareTo() instead of "<" operator in bubbleBort. This will solve the issue with private variable.

And after these changes BubbleSort can be rewritten as static generic method.

```
public static void bubbleSort<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable{
    int i, j;
    T temp;

    for (i = (x-1); i >= 0; i--) 
{    
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
{    
    if(array[j - 1].CompareTo(array[j]) == 1) 
{
    temp = array[j - 1];
    array[j - 1] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp; 
} } } }
```

Comment: Turns out that I was mistaken on the field to be sorted by, is this applicable on strings?

Comment: This solution is independent of concrete comparison mode.